# ImportError: No module named obd

Tags: python, import, obd-ii

I have installed obd library in python using : pip install obd. But when I tried to import eventlet this error occured:

```
pip install obd
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: obd in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial==3.* in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from obd) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pint==0.7.* in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from obd) (0.7.2)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python obd_hud_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "obd_hud_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import obd
ImportError: No module named obd
```

ow to rectify this error?

P.S : I am using Python 2.7

Comment: You say you're using Python 2.7 but your pip command is installing modules to a `python3.6` directory. I'd imagine your problem has something to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check which packages are installed with:

```
pip list
```

Hightlight specific package:

```
# Linux or other Unix-like systems
pip list | grep -i obd
# Windows
pip list | findstr /I obd
```

If it is not displayed, It is likely that something went wrong during the installation. You should reinstall.
OR
You should try to install a specific version

```
pip install "obd==0.7.1"
```